# Fake click using @testing-library/user-event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, user-event

I want to test that a tracking event occurs when clicking a link in react. However I do get a `Error: Not implemented: navigation` as an effect of what happens when the link is clicked. I am testing with jest and [@testing-library/user-event](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event#clickelement-eventinit-options).

I now want to mock or stub so that no navigation attempt takes place when the userEvent is fired as I am only interested to see the tracking event taking place. How can I do this?

```js
userEvent.click(item);

expect(Ga.trackEvent).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(Ga.trackEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myModal', 'open');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test is actually trying to navigate using window.location

You will need to mock that out before trying the user event

```js
let assignMock = jest.fn();

delete window.location;
window.location = { assign: assignMock };

afterEach(() => {
  assignMock.mockClear();
});
```